# Javascript if empty not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

So I'm trying to change the color of a submit button if the form is empty. So I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong, since I'm super new, but here's the code I have at the moment.

My partial form

```
 <div class="field">
<input type="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div class="submit">
<input type="submit" value="Reset Password">
</div>
```

And the JS

```
if ($('#field'.is(':empty')){
     $("#submit").css({"backgroundColor":"black"});
 }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Probably a closing parenthesis missing after `#field`?

Comment: both field and submit are classes.. try doing this if ($('.field'.is(':empty')){
     $(".submit").css({"backgroundColor":"black"});
 }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You specified id's in your jQuery when it should be classes -

```
if ($('.field'.is(':empty'))){ // field is a class, not an id, extra parentheses needed
     $("#submit").css({"backgroundColor":"black"});
 }
```

BUT, what you should be doing is checking the value of the email field, because the input makes the field "not empty" which means that the above **WILL NEVER WORK**

What you need to do is check whether the value of the input has any length, the input's container is not relevant:

```
if(!$('input[name="email"]').val().length) {
    $('#submit').css({"backgroundColor":"black"});
}
```

EDIT: Finalized code after the OP made his desires clearer (validating e-mail) -

```
$('input[name="email"]').change(function () {
    // regex to validate e-mail address
    var regex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    var validEmail = regex.test( $(this).val() );
    if(true == validEmail) {
        $('#submit').css({
            "background": "#CCCCCC",
            "color": "black"
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: It is because you haven't named your input. It must have a name, like name="email" (fiddle coming).

Comment: Are you sure? When I load the page, it doesn't show a black submit button, rather the default button. I'm not sure if you understood what I'm trying to achieve. When the page loads, it would be one color, but when the _empty_ fields are filled it would change. In my question I think it was the other way around, but it would still equal the same thing. I'm trying to do something similar to the iCloud website, where both fields have to be filled up, then the submit button changes color https://www.icloud.com/

Comment: Ah! So you want the reverse of what you originally asked....let me change some things.

Comment: Added a link as an example. In the previous comment

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/NQV7L/1/ is the updated fiddle. You have to set the original condition and then have a change act on the element

Comment: Will that last fiddle work for you, or do you need more?

Comment: When I enter a valid email, then use an invalid one, the box doesn't turn black

Comment: OK - you didn't ask for e-mail validation, you just asked for a condition where your form element is empty. You should have stated this in your original post and follow up comments.

Comment: Here is the updated query with all of your requirements - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/NQV7L/2/

Comment: No, no. Say I use `email@email.com`. Then go back and get rid of everything in the input, the button is still black. Is there some sort of release?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/NQV7L/3/ is the update. All that needed to be done was add the else condition.

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($('#field').is(':empty')){
    $("#submit").css({"backgroundColor":"black"});

}
```

You have to close the paren on '#field' so that you get a jquery object back to run the `is` function on.

Also your 'field' is a class not an id so you need a `.` not a `#` selector.

All this of course also depends on you moving the class `field` to the input, since you don't actually want to check for `empty` on a div.

So you actually want to do this with your whole code:

```
<div>
    <input class="field" type="email" placeholder="Email">
</div>
<div>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Reset Password">
</div>

if ($('.field').is(':empty')){
    $(".submit").css({"backgroundColor":"black"});
}
```

Comment: 'field' is a class in the OP's example and it will never be empty as long as the input is in it.

Comment: Can you submit a fiddle or something? I can't seem to get the color to change....

Answer (score 0):

`field` is a class and you have a syntax error in there. Closing parenthesis after `'field'` is missing 
Try:

```
if ($('.field').is(':empty')){
     $("#submit").css({"backgroundColor":"black"});
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Class start with a dot (.)
I'd start with hash #

That is your error

Answer (score 0):

You've got some syntax errors in your code that are keeping it from executing properly:

1. You are querying the DOM object with an **id** of `field`, when you actually assigned your div a **class** of `field`. Change your query to `$('.field')` and it should work.
2. You neglected to close the parens on your call to the jQuery function `$`, this will prevent it from properly returning a jQuery object on which to call the `is()` method.
3. You are using the jQuery `:empty` pseudoselector to check if your div has any value entered, but this is not the intended use of this function. Rather, you should use the `val()` method directly on the input itself to check if the input has had anything entered into itself, and use that as your conditional.
4. You are querying your submit button with an **id** of `#submit`, but your submit input has not been assigned any id. You can either assign it an id of `#submit` or query it by its `type` attribute.

With these errors corrected, your code should look like this:

```
if (!$('.field > input').val()){
  $("input[type='submit']").css("backgroundColor", "black");
}
```

You can check out the working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/H5STS/1/)

Comment: But this will not work, because .field is never empty.

Comment: `$('.field').val() === undefined`, always.